# Android: Alternative widgets / 2D framework for developing a game

Tags: android, 2d, widget

my next project will be to develop a little game for android. In fact it will be more based on textual in- and outputs, so i don't need best hd graphics but nice looking "standard widgets".

I will mainly need Buttons, Checkboxes, RadioButtons, TextFields, SpinEdits so in general only the standard textual widgets. As i don't like the included ones in Android ("no looking cool enough", customization difficult, ..) i'm searching for alternative widgets or an possiblity to draw to them easily for example with an 2D framework. Themes are welcome.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

you can use canvas, opengl or games engine, for example http://www.andengine.org/